# Creating android app to remotely control my computer

Tags: java, android, remote-access

I wish to control my computer remotely from my android mobile. I know that apps are available for the same. But what if i wish to develop one on my own? Kindly someone suggest the available API's to remotely control my pc from mobile and perform tasks, like shutting it down, opening various applications of my pc etc.

Comment: Have you checked how other apps are doing this? I think most of them do it the same way.

Comment: As said by **CommonsWare** there is no API for it. May can try re-engineering if u get APK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> available API's to remotely control my pc from mobile and perform tasks, like shutting it down, opening various applications of my pc

There are no "available API's to remotely control my pc from mobile and perform tasks, like shutting it down, opening various applications of my pc". You would write all of that yourself.

Comment: But check this out! I asked this on this forum because being a newbie, I was and still am not sure whether this is what I wanted.(link:http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/RemoteService.html)

Comment: @rahulserver: That has nothing to do with controlling a PC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use socket programming where your computer will be the server and your phone will be the client. You can connect to your computer using a TCP connection and a fixed port number. You need to write a program for both sides.

Once you are able to send a specific message from your android device to your computer. You should easily perform the necessary task (`like shutting it down, opening various applications of my pc etc`) on the server side.

There are a lot of android socket programming tutorials on the internet.