# Android running command on windows

Tags: android, windows, shared-libraries, remote-access

is there any android library or application to send command or keystroke or mouse click to Windows from android app?

I have an android project that need to run an application on windows with a touch on android.. the android app will have 4 big button which is used to send command to windows..

I expect there is an android library and server app for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10140812/1291122 .There are no android libraries for that. You need to write it all yourself!.

However I feel(haven't tried yet) that you can use the [bluetooth API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) to establish a connection  between your android device and your windows pc and exchange data(command strings like "LEFT","OPEN","SHUTDOWN") by managing the [connections](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection).At the same time, you may have simple [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) running on windows which accepts connection from your android device and decodes the command strings received and performs actions accordingly.

There are many [applications](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2033284/how-to-control-your-pc-with-your-android-phone.htmlhttp://www.pcworld.com/article/2033284/how-to-control-your-pc-with-your-android-phone.html) available in the market which do the same thing. I guess they use a similar(not exact) approach.